# Why were Chip and Dale renamed to Tic and Tac?

Tags: anglais, noms-propres, surnoms

TV Series "Chip 'n Dale Rescue Rangers" are "Tic et Tac, les rangers du risque" in French. Why were the protagonists renamed? Do their original names sound obscene or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The play on words (Chip and Dale, Chippendale) would be have been lost if the French caracters had had the same name (Chip et Dale are not very believable names for caracters in a French cartoon). There was therefore no reason to keep the same names in French and the protagonists were renamed. "Tic, tac" is the sound of a clock (like "tick, tock" in English).

I you take a look at the Wikipedia article, you'll see that Chip and Dale were also renamed in other languages (Ahörnchen und Behörnchen in German, Chip og Chap in Danish, etc.) !

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_%27n%27_Dale

The same phenomenon can be observed for Donald Duck's nephews. Here is a list of the translations of their names into other languages: http://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/a7yKedq_700b_v1.jpg

Comment: Actually, I was confused since in Russian localized version (the first one I've watched) they are still Chip and Dale ("Чип и Дейл"). However, other characters - for instance, Monty and Zipper - were renamed as well, so this practice seems really common.

Comment: Also it's pretty relevant that (I'M pretty sure) the character renaming predated the tv series.

Comment: @Circeus Do you reckon that if the TV series had come out before the translation into other languages, the names would have been set in stone and could not have been translated, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I would assume that whichever name came first would have been kept, but as far as I know, they received their names in some of the Disney shorts that long predated the tv series. That's all I meant.